# How can I create a map by using gmapping and a Hokuyo-Scanner?

Tags: slam, navigation, slam-gmapping, hokuyo, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

i have a Hokuyo-Scanner (UTM-30LX-EW) and i would like to create a  2D-Map with gmapping and visualize this in realtime with Rviz.
Can anyone tell me  what the best way is to do this?

my Steps are:
$ roscore 
$ rosrun urg_node urg_node _ip_address:="192.168.0.10" scan:=base_scan
$ rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:base_scan
$ rosrun rviz rviz --> add map --> set topic to "map" --> set fixed frame to "map"

Rviz shows a massage "no map received!"

Is there any simple way to create and view a map by using Hokuyo-Scanner over Ethernet?
or what do i wrong?

thanks and best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203381/how-can-i-create-a-map-by-using-gmapping-and-a-hokuyo-scanner?/) by [Twista3579](https://answers.ros.org/users/21669/twista3579/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-02-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-02-18**:
Do you have odometry?

**Comment by [Twista3579](https://answers.ros.org/users/21669/twista3579/) on 2015-02-18**:
No, i have only the scanner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gmapping requires odometry. Check out hector_slam.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2